# Do ec2 snapshots wait for mysql queries to finish before executing?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I can't find the link anymore but I remember reading that if an ec2 snapshot is being taken while a write to the database is made - if you create an ami from that snapshot and launch an instance from that ami, it may not load correctly due to an error in binary.  Are ec2 snapshots taken while mysql queries are being executed, or do they wait for the query to finish, then lock the db and then take the snapshot?

Also - What are snapshotting best practices for mysql applications?  Would I need to lock my database before taking a snapshot?

Finally - I occasionally take mysqldumps of this database.  When you take a mysqldump, does it freeze the database from writes, then proceed with dumping the data or would I need to lock my database before taking a dump?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, when you make a snapshot you are not guaranteeing that the file system in not in the middle of a write. It is best practice to first freeze your volume if it is a high use volume. I use XFS file systems and simply use XFS freeze to halt the file system. (Don't forget to unfreeze it)
2. Best practice is to flush your mysql tables, lock them, and freeze the file system. This way you ensure the data will not be corrupted.
3. mysqldump is much better at making sure your data is not corrupted. You can rely on mysqldump to give you good data without having to freeze the whole world.

Check out this [script](https://github.com/chandlerh/EBS-Snapshot.git) I wrote to do this.

I usually have a mysql master-slave setup and do my ebs snapshots on the slave once a day, and I do mysql dumps and upload them to s3 more often.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough advice.  How do you go about freezing the filesystem?  I thought ec2 snapshots do this automatically, so that all I would need to do is `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK`, take a snapshot then kill the running process `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK`

Comment: To freeze the file system you run a xfs_freeze command (if the file system is a XFS) see this: http://linux.die.net/man/8/xfs_freeze.

Comment: But to answer the other part of your question, I have gotten both sides of the story when asking if you should freeze the file system. Since my EBS volumes are only really written to by MySQL and as long as I have the tables frozen, then I am good. But to be safe it cant hurt to freeze the file system. If you are writing logs to this disk, or if MySQL isn't running on its own volume, etc, etc. I would freeze the disk. But if you are certain it is only MySQL writing to the disk, then you probably will be good.